# AzDo: Exporting test results from multiple test runs

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests, export

I need the test result details data for individual tests (all tests) across multiple test runs for custom analysis.

Is there a way to export this data out of AzDo without going into each test run individually and downloading multiple trx files separately from each run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to export this data out of AzDo without going into each test run individually and downloading multiple trx files separately from each run?

As far as I know, there is no such way on UI page to meet your requirements.

Based on my test, when I run the automatic test to get the test attachments (.trx files) in test run, it doesn't seem to support downloading multiple attachments from multiple test runs at once.

Here are two methods to download attachments:

1. You could navigate to the target test run and download test run attachments manually.

[image: Download attachments]

**Updates:**

2. You could use Rest API to download the test run attachments .

Rest Api Steps:

Step1: You need to get the `Test Run ID` in Test Run Page.

Step2: Run this Rest API: [Attachments - Get Test Run Attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/get%20test%20run%20attachments?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). Then you could get he `attachment id`.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/attachments?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Step3：Run this Rest API: [Attachments - Get Test Run Attachment Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/get%20test%20run%20attachment%20zip?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). You could directly download the attachments.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/attachments/{attachmentId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Comment: thanks! I've found the REST API and using it, it's very good, has eveything I need and more.

Comment: Please add the runs API to the answer and I'll accept it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: @axk I have updated the answer. Please check it. Thanks.